# Git isn't pushing everything on my initial commit for my ASP.NET MVC projects. It's always missing references?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I use SourceTree.. i don't have anything in the .gitignore files.. I never had this problem with other types of projects before.. For some reason with my ASP.NET MVC project.. i'll make an initial commit and i'll pull right away in a diff location just to make sure and it's always erroring because it's missing references.. i dont think it's pushing ALL the files and it's missing some.

I've tried it the command line way using these commands here:

```
git add --all
```

and also tried

```
git add --all :/
```

nothing works.  everytime i pull to see if it included everything, i always get a lot of references errors as it seems like it's just not pushing everything.. i'm so frustrated.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

okay so a coworker was able to find the solution for me.

```
git config --get core.excludesfile
```

found that i had a weird global hidden file somewhere random in a hidden folder

```
git config --globalcore.excludesfile false
```

that disabled it